# Alert Dialog Customization

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I just added an Alert Dialog that comes up when the back button is clicked. It's set to the default android alert I believe. Is there anyway to customize how the alert dialog box looks such as change the background or set a drawable to the background? I am new to this so I am not sure what to do. Thanks, and my code is below that I used for the alert dialog.

Alert Dialog:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Handle the back button
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //Ask the user if they want to quit
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle(R.string.quit)
            .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Stop the activity and pause media player
                     mainSound.pause();
                    MainActivity.this.finish();    
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
            .show();

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this..

Create your xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
```

And then you can set your layout on the builder with the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup)    findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root));
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
```

EDIT:

You should rearrange your code to something like this...
Create a AlertDialog.Builder at class level.

```
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
```

In your onCreate() create your AlertDialog

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup)     findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root));


  //Ask the user if they want to quit
        builder
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle(R.string.quit)
        .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //Stop the activity and pause media player
                 mainSound.pause();
                MainActivity.this.finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
        .setView(dailogLayout);





public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

     builder.show();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: No problem, Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would've written a more detailed answer here, but google wrote this tutorial much better than I could: just go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html, and go to **Creating a Custom Dialog**.
This is probably one of the best tutorials google wrote for Android.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that out it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

how to create a CustumDialog is explained in the Android Docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
At the buttom of the page you can find a point called "Creating a Custom Dialog".