# Fully custom dialog in Android with the same look regardless device

Tags: android, dialog

I have to build a dialog that looks exactly the same across different devices regardless of the OS theme. At the moment, I created an `AlertDialog` and I call `alertDialog.setView(myLayout)`. This creates a dialog with my view. However, some parts of the dialog box (outer part and border line) are still OS based and they look different in my Samsung or HTC.

Is there anyway to create the actual box?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888075/alert-dialog-customization could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for this

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FullyscutomDialo extends Dialog{

public FullyscutomDialo(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    //do what you need before closing here
    super.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set your custom layout here
    //use layout attribut just like activity
}

 }
```

then use two line to show it from activity(May be onclickevent etc)

```
         FullyscutomDialo hh=new FullyscutomDialo (this);
         hh.show()
```

**Edited For Transparent Dialog**

use In onCreate of dialog class

```
 this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Cheers :):)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify Themes in views or activities.
Have a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Answer (score 2):

create xml file.
and use this java code.

```
                        info_dialog = new Dialog(ActivityName.this);
                        info_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        info_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.info);                          
                        info_dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing custom dialog look at the tutorial it is great
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
about the borders 
see here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
you may also make use of this It have some great Ideas