# Android custom dialog layout doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I don't understand why my dialog layout behaves strange. If I use `android:layout="wrap_content"` for the last widget, It makes the dialog very narrow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam bibendum leo eget eros mattis nec eleifend nulla elementum. Suspendisse suscipit suscipit enim in mollis. "    
    />

    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't remind me later"    
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"    
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code.

```
private void showDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dial);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog title");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: see my answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894300/fully-custom-dialog-in-android-with-the-same-look-regardless-device/8894444#8894444.and upvote if you like

Comment: had the same problem, though i had to use fill_parent since it was 1.6. Strange indeed but probably got something to do with the layout calculation of a window on a window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Match_parent** means that the size of this widget, will be the size of the parent...so, if parent have 200 pixels, so the widget will have. Instead, if you use **wrap_content**...means that the widget will have the size equals with it's content. So if a TextView contains text for about 50 pixels long, then this will be the size of the widget. **Base on this definitions, you can construct better now your layouts.**

Comment: I have tested the code on two devices: [Samsung Galaxy SL I9003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_SL_I9003) (Android 2.3.7) and [GT-N8000 (3G & Wifi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_10.1) (Android 4.1.2). A dialog is OK unless I use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for the button on _Samsung Galaxy SL I9003_; both `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` work well on the tablet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My dialog was very narrow, no matter what I set the layouts and their child controls to. I was able to fix the problem by doing a clean build in Eclipse though.