# Android AlertDialog design same on all Android Versions

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it correct that an AlertDialog may look different on devices with different android versions? And if yes, how can I make it look the same for all devices? Do I need to make a custom AlertDialog or can I just somehow overwrite the design?

Thanks

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894300/fully-custom-dialog-in-android-with-the-same-look-regardless-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that an AlertDialog may look different on devices with different android versions?

It's all right, android change design, but users that uses old version see old design.

If you want to provide your own design for alert dialog see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870997/958370) answer.

If you just want to provide holo design for your app in any version of android - you can use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Use `custom AlertDialog`. It will looks same on all versions.[click here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)